# how do i fix this, it appears each time Windows 7 starts.

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

This is the message that appears at startup. there was a problem starting c:\users\name\appdata\local\conduit\backgroundcontainer\backgroundcontainer.dll the specifiedmodule could not be found. Windows 7 home premium.

Comment: Have you tried the answer given in the link above?

Answer (score -2):

The error is produced by one of your startup programs.Press windows+r and type msconfig a.nd hit enter.On startup tab look for the program and disable it.hope it will work

---